# Usar pluck laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Quiero que al llamar a un metodo de mi controlador de laravel devuelva un JSON con los datos que una DDBB.
Tengo una tabla Produtos con los campos:

> id, nombre, idCategoria, idGenero, stock

Una tabla Categoria con:

> id, nombre, created

Y una tabla Genero con:

> id, nombre, created

En el modelo de productos tengo añadida las siguientes funciones:

```
public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'idCategoria');
    }
    public function genero()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Genero::class, 'idGenero');
    }
```

En el modelo de categoria y en el modelo genero tengo añadido:

```
public function productos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Productos::class);
    }
```

El caso es que quiero que me muestre todos los campos de la tabla productos con los 'idCategoria' y 'idGenero' substituidos por el nombre de su categoria y genero correspondiente.
Estoy intentado esto:

```
public function index_front() {
        $products = Productos::with('categoria')->get()->pluck('id', 'nombre','categoria.nombre', 'stock');
        return json_encode($products);

    }
```

Pero no consigo hacer que me muestre lo que necesito.

Comment: ¿Qué resultado está obteniendo actualmente ? si hace un `dd($products)`

Comment: `{"pacman":1}` Habiendo creado un producto, categoria y genero de prueba.

Comment: coloque el la vista ** <?= var_dump($products) ?> ** hay me va a mostrar el array de la consulta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo implementar los [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources).

1.- En consola `php artisan make:resource ProductoResource`

Esto te va a generar la clase `App\Http\Resources\ProductoResource`

2.- Modificá este archivo ubicado en app/Http/Resourses/ProductoResource.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProductoResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request); // Comentá esta línea
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'nombre' => $this->nombre,
            'categoria' => $this->categoria->nombre,
            'stock' => $this->stock,
        ];
    }
}
```

3.- En el controlador hacé lo siguiente

```
public function index_front() {
    $products = Productos::all();
    return \App\Http\Resources\ProductoResource::collection($products);
}
```

Tenés infinitas opciones usando los Api Resources, sobre todo si necesitas respuestas json. No necesitas hacer json_encode(). Leete bien la documentación y vas a poder sacarle el jugo a esta funcionalidad de Laravel.
Tabién podés paginar resultados! hay algunos tutoriales en youtube al respecto.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente usa un select y pon las 2 relaciones en el with

```
public function index_front() {
        $products = Productos::select('productos.*', 'categoria.nombre as categoria', 'genero.nombre as genero')->with(['categoria', 'genero'])->get();
        return json_encode($products);
    }
```

Comment: Me dice que no encuentra categoria.nombre en la field list

Answer (score 0):

en la parte de la consulta coloque el with

```
$consulta=Produtos::with('idCategoria_pk','idGenero_pk')->get();
```

en el modelo Produtos coloque lo siguiente

```
funcion public function idCategoria_pk()
    {
        //archivo de modelo y el campo foreign_key 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria','idCategoria');   
    } 
funcion public function idGenero_pk()
    {
        //archivo de modelo y el campo foreign_key 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Genero','idGenero');   
    }
```

y en la vista coloque lo siguiente

```
@foreach($consultaas $lists)
                    <td class="col1">{{ $lists->descripcion }}</td>

                    {{$lists->idCategoria_pk->nombre}}  
                    {{$lists->idGenero_pk->nombre}}          

                    </td>
            @endforeach
```